# Adding mouse event to dynamic created element Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I was just wondering have anyone tried doing something like this(this is within a vuejs created method):

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
    let bar = document.createElement('div');
  bar.className = this.items[i].colour;
  bar.style.cssText = `width: ${this.items[i].weight}%`;
  bar.setAttribute("mouseover", this.showBlock(500, false)); //not working
    document.querySelector('.bar').appendChild(bar);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/phfilly/eywraw8t/167799/

I’m trying to add a hover mouse event(line 32) to the newly created element. Is there another way to achieve something like this?

Comment: It should be like this . bar.addEventListener("mouseover", this.showBlock(500, false));       Just normal javascript

Comment: Why don't you use Vue to generate the elements for `items`? Then you can add `@mouseover` directive.

Comment: @saiyan I've tried with addEventListener too...still no reaction in the showBlock method.

Comment: @juzraai that is a good idea let me try that

Comment: Is this not more what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/n8p917Lr/

Comment: @Bert Thank you kind sir, that is spot on. I don't know what I made it more complex for myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem:**

Let's look at the problematic line:

```
bar.setAttribute("mouseover", this.showBlock(500, false));
```

I see the following issues:

- It first calculates the **return value** of `this.showBlock(500, false)`, then sets it to `mouseover` attribute. That value is most likely `undefined`, since your function doesn't return anything.
- The value doesn't even matter, because `mouseover` attribute has absolutely no meaning in HTML, nor in Vue, which looks for `v-on:mouseover` or `@mouseover`.
- Vue only looks for these attributes/directives when it is initialized, but you are adding the elements **after** Vue initialization.

**Possible solutions:**

**A)** Make sure your Vue model is accessible as a global variable (like `window.app`), then you can do the trick with `onmouseover` HTML attribute and stringifying your function call:

```
bar.setAttribute("onmouseover", "app.showBlock(500, false)");
```

**B)** Add an event listener instead of an attribute. Something like this:

```
bar.addEventListener("mouseover", function () { app.showBlock(500, false); });
```

This also requires your Vue instance to be accessible.

See a complete solution in [@saiyan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51326994/2418224).

**C)** As you are not doing anything that Vue can't do, you can (and I advise you to) use Vue to create your elements instead. In my opinion, that's the point of Vue, to ease the pain of creating and modifying elements. Based on your quoted `for` loop, a Vue implementation would look like this (in your HTML):

```
<div class="bar">
  <div v-for="i in items" :class="i.colour" :style="{ width: i.weight + '%' }" @mouseover="showBlock(500, false)"></div>
</div>
```

For a complete solution, please check out [@Bert's fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n8p917Lr/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this . I made some changes in your jsfiddle code.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
        let bar = document.createElement('div');
      bar.className = this.items[i].colour;
      bar.style.cssText = `width: ${this.items[i].weight}%`;
            // ?
     // bar.setAttribute("mouseover", this.showBlock(500, false));
        document.querySelector('.bar').appendChild(bar);



    }
    var that=this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      document.querySelector('.bar').childNodes.forEach(function(e,y){
        e.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){that.showBlock(500, false)});
      });},100);
```

worked for me in jsfiddle